# Why doesn't `flextable` show all the rows of the dataframe?

Tags: r, flextable

My dataframe has 60 rows but `flextable` only show not show 10 of them. Why?

```r
df <- structure(list(Script.x = c("Mandaic", "Mandaic", "Mandaic", "Mandaic", "Mandaic", "Mandaic", "Gothic", "Gothic", "Gothic", "Gothic", "Gothic", "Gothic", "Ugaritic", "Ugaritic", "Ugaritic", "Ugaritic", "Ugaritic", "Ugaritic", "MeroiticCursive", "MeroiticCursive", "MeroiticCursive", "MeroiticCursive", "MeroiticCursive", "MeroiticCursive", "Hangul", "Hangul", "Hangul", "Hangul", "Hangul", "Hangul", "Ogham", "Ogham", "Ogham", "Ogham", "Ogham", "Ogham", "BassaVah", "BassaVah", "BassaVah", "BassaVah", "BassaVah", "BassaVah", "Tagbanwa", "Tagbanwa", "Tagbanwa", "Tagbanwa", "Tagbanwa", "Tagbanwa", "Buginese", "Buginese", "Buginese", "Buginese", "Buginese", "Buginese", "SylotiNagri", "SylotiNagri", "SylotiNagri", "SylotiNagri", "SylotiNagri", "SylotiNagri"), pair = c("0841_0851_Mandaic", "0843_0850_Mandaic", "0846_0855_Mandaic", "0849_0856_Mandaic", "084A_084D_Mandaic", "0853_0857_Mandaic", "10332_10338_Gothic", "10334_10340_Gothic", "10336_10348_Gothic", "1033A_10342_Gothic", "1033B_1034A_Gothic", "10345_10347_Gothic", "10380_10397_Ugaritic", "10381_1038B_Ugaritic", "10382_1039C_Ugaritic", "10386_10398_Ugaritic", "10388_1039D_Ugaritic", "10389_1038C_Ugaritic", "109A5_109AA_MeroiticCursive", "109A9_109B2_MeroiticCursive", "109AC_109B3_MeroiticCursive", "109AD_109AE_MeroiticCursive", "109AF_109B5_MeroiticCursive", "109B0_109B4_MeroiticCursive", "110A_1164_Hangul", "110B_116B_Hangul", "1112_1175_Hangul", "1169_116E_Hangul", "116A_116F_Hangul", "116D_1172_Hangul", "1683_168B_Ogham", "1685_168C_Ogham", "1687_168D_Ogham", "1689_168A_Ogham", "168E_168F_Ogham", "1695_1696_Ogham", "16AD1_16AE7_BassaVah", "16ADA_16AE4_BassaVah", "16ADC_16AE9_BassaVah", "16ADD_16ADE_BassaVah", "16ADF_16AE8_BassaVah", "16AE1_16AE2_BassaVah", "1761_1762_Tagbanwa", "1763_176C_Tagbanwa", "1764_1768_Tagbanwa", "1765_1770_Tagbanwa", "1769_176E_Tagbanwa", "176A_176F_Tagbanwa", "1A05_1A0A_Buginese", "1A07_1A12_Buginese", "1A08_1A13_Buginese", "1A0C_1A0F_Buginese", "1A10_1A15_Buginese", "1A14_1A16_Buginese", "A805_A807_SylotiNagri", "A810_A812_SylotiNagri", "A811_A813_SylotiNagri", "A814_A822_SylotiNagri", "A818_A81C_SylotiNagri", "A819_A81B_SylotiNagri"), LettresPair = c("ࡁ ࡑ", "ࡃ ࡐ‎", "ࡆ‎ ࡕ", "ࡉ‎ ࡖ", "ࡊ ࡍ", "ࡓ ࡗ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "‎ ‎", "‎ ", " ‎", " NA", "NA ", "‎ ‎", "ㅆ ㅒ", "ㅇ ㅙ", "ㅎ ㅣ", "ㅗ ㅜ", "ㅘ ㅝ", "ㅛ ㅠ", "ᚃ ᚋ", "ᚅ ᚌ", "ᚇ ᚍ", "ᚉ ᚊ", "ᚎ ᚏ", "ᚕ ᚖ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA")), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(dplyr)
library(flextable)

df %>% 
  as_flextable()
```

[image]

Comment: `?as_flextable.data.frame max_row The number of rows to print. Default to 10.`

Comment: `as_flextable.data.frame` creates a `Simple summary of a data.frame as a flextable`. You could use `flextable()` instead.